# Which values do I use to filter a specific frequency with an RLC circuit?

Tags: filter-design

I have a RLC circuit with transformation $$H(s) = \frac{R}{Ls+\frac{1}{Cs}+R}$$ and I know that by setting $s=j\omega$ I can obtain the frequency response of this system. What I don't understand is how I can use the frequency response graph to decide which values I should set on R and f $(L=2\pi f, C=1\mu F)$ to filter out a specific frequency from the input signal $u(t)$.

Lets say that I have u(t) which I know consists of two signals, $400 Hz$ and $800 Hz$ (by calculating the amplitude spectrum $U(\omega)$ and plotting the graph). How do I design a filter to filter out one of them?

Comment: The circuit cannot filter out (in the sense of completely remove) any specific frequency; it passes all frequencies but _attenuates_ (meaning reduces the amplitude of) different frequencies differently. In your question, _both_ the 400 Hz signal and the 800 Hz signal will appear at the output but reduced in amplitude by factors of $a$ and $b$, say. You cannot choose to make $b$ very large (remove 800Hz almost completely) without increasing $a$ also. So you need to decide what _ratio_ you want $a$ and $b$ to have, and choose R, L, C accordingly. I am ignoring phase shifts here for simplicity.

Comment: this is pretty standard stuff in 2nd or 3rd year undergraduate electrical engineering.  do you want someone to repeat what's in the textbooks about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electrical design.